# File Related Error when looping through Excel Files in a folder

Tags: power-automate-desktop

I'm fairly new to PAD, but I've started receiving an error when my process runs on a VDI.

The error is:

[image]

I can tell that the file causing the error is a temporary file being created. I think I need the loop to skip over any temp files. I've tried adding an `IF` statement to skip over temp files, but it doesn't seem to be identifying the file and skipping it as intended. My flow will error and end.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is a section of my code in PAD - the error occurs on line 18:
[image]

EDIT: Additional Info
The error occurs on line #18 - "Launch Excel"
The temp Excel files do not exist in the folder when the process begins. They are being created during the PAD run.

Comment: what line is it failing on?

Comment: @CobyC it fails on line #18 "Launch Excel". Assuming that happens because the file is already open. But I don't think it should be getting those temp files caught into the loop? Those temp files don't exist when the process begins.

Comment: Some additional PAD links related to the answer below [variable manipulation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/desktop-flows/variable-manipulation) and [data type properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/desktop-flows/datatype-properties#files)

Answer (score 0):

You can access the filename directly from the current item in the loop, in your case `itm_ProcessTransactions_CurrentFile` and check if it starts with ~$ if it does skip to the next item in the loop.

[image: skipitem]

the If statement:

[image: ifstatement]

or alternatively you could set the if statement to only continue when the filename does not start with ~$

[image: notstartwith]

or you could replace both IF statements with something like:
[image: bothifinone]

[image: ifreplaced]

Comment: Thanks @CobyC I made the first adjustment that you mentioned and will report back after I run it.

Comment: sorry, a different error started happening earlier in the process that I'm trying to figure out how to fix, so I haven't been able to test the part in the process that you were helping with, yet. New error is when launching/navigating Edge - "browser instance must be web browser instance"